# Is it possible to use POD(plain old documentation) with Python?

Tags: python, perl-pod

I was wondering if it is possible to use POD(plain old documentation) with Python? And how should I do it?

Comment: Why do you need that. Python has its very own docstring format which gets interpreted by `pydoc`. If you use POD, users of your module would need a tool to read it. Are you sure this is what you want? If you just want to document your code, use python's docstring.

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be a directly supported way to use POD inline in a Python file. However, Python modules (including the Python standard library) are documented using [reStructuredText](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/rest_syntax.html). This is usually done using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), which produces documentation from reStructuredText-formatted docstrings. Sphinx and rst were specifically designed to fill a similar niche to POD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use '''.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                       

'''
=pod
                                                                                     
=head1 NAME
...
=cut
'''

import sys
```