# Module for Python so that you can generate a free-standing, self-documenting command line utility ala Perl's pod2man/pod2usage?

Tags: python, command-line, documentation-generation

All I can find is this reference:

[Is it possible to use POD(plain old documentation) with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034512/is-it-possible-to-use-podplain-old-documentation-with-python)

which looks like you have to generate a whole separate set of docs to go with code.

I would like to try Python for making cmdline utils, but when I do this with Perl I can embed the docs directly in the source, and use the Pod2Usage module along with Getopt so that any of my scripts can be run like this:

```
cmd --man
```

and this triggers the pod system to dump documentation that is embedded in the script in man-page format. It can also generate shorter (synopsis), or medium formats.

It looks like I could use the pydoc code and kind of reverse engineer it to sort-of do the task (at least showing the full documentation), but I am hoping something better already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [python-modargs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-modargs) package lets you create self-documenting command line interfaces. You define a function for each command you want to make available, and the function's docstring becomes the help text for that function. The function's keyword arguments become named arguments and python-modargs will parse inline comments after the keyword arguments to be help text for that argument.

I use python-modargs to generate the command line interface for dexy, here is the module which defines the commands:
https://github.com/ananelson/dexy/blob/027954f9234363d506225d40b675b3d6478994f4/dexy/commands.py#L144

You need to implement a help_command method to get the generated help, it's a 1-liner.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. It is also good you included an example, as I never would have found it given the lack of docs on the module page!

Answer (score 0):

I think [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) may be what you're looking for.

It certainly isn't quite the same as POD, as you have to call **pydoc** itself (e.g. `pydoc myscript.py`), but I guess it can be a good starting point.

Of course, you can always add pydoc support for your script by importing from it and using it's functions/classes.
Checkout [pydoc's own cli implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l2276) for the best example.